# Android - Fixed / Stationary Background between Activities?

Tags: android

In my app, I want to have a single background image that I use for all pages/activities. When I switch activities, say clicking a button to goto another activity, all the elements on the screen, as well as the background, slides off the screen to the left. At the same time, all the new elements from the new activity and it's background slide onto the screen from the right.

Is it possible to keep the background stationary so that it doesn't slide off and on the screen when switching between activities? Is this where Themes come into play? Or do I need to just have a single layout that is dynamically altered whenever I want to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In phones, Yes last option is the one which you will have to use, dynamically alter the layout accordingly. so that background does not change.
Since in activities one will be reloading the xml again.

In case of honeycomb, you can manage with fragments, where you just reload the fragments where as background remains the same.